# How to inject content script in the specific url from other urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to acheive such a that when I am on the other url still my content script should get injected into specific url. Is this possible?

currently I am using scripting api to inject the content script but it will inject the script within the specific url only

```
document
  .getElementById("injectButton")
  .addEventListener("click", async function () {
    const currentTab = await getCurrentTab();
    if (currentTab) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: currentTab.id },
        files: ["content_script.js"],
      });
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to get the current tab.");
    }
  });
```

Not sure how to proceed

Comment: The API can do what you want by default, so please clarify "when I am on the other url", show how this code runs (where), show your manifest.json permissions and host_permissions.

Comment: By specific url and other url do you imply specific tab and other tab?
Do you want to inject content script from one tab into other tab? 
Your question is unclear, please add more context.